# Ubuntu booting error ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, acpi, busybox

I'm getting the following error when I boot my `ubuntu busybox v1.21.1`.

```
ACPI PCC probe failed
....
....
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev)
```

I reboot 2 or 3 times but still the same error is coming. I'm unable to switch to root via `sudo` as well. If anyone already faced this error, please help me how to solve this.[image]